# Bullet uses host's camera to tell where to fire rather than using client's camera

Tags: unity, 2d, multiplayer

## Problem

In my 2d top-down multiplayer game, whenever the client player fires a bullet, the bullet is supposed to go towards the direction of the clients mouse. However, when the client fires, it goes towards the direction of the host's mouse, despite having locally disabled all cameras other than the camera attached to the player.

## Scripts

*This script is attached to the player.*

For disabling the camera - `if(!isLocalPlayer) {cam.enabled = false; return;}`

---

*This script is attached to the player.*

For spawning in the bullet

```
    void Update () {
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
        return;

        if (fireRate == 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    } else
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > timeToFire)
        {
            timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }
}

public void Shoot ()
{
    Debug.Log("Arrived at Shoot()");

    Instantiate(BasicBullet, firePoint);
}
```

---

*This script is attached to the bullet.*

For firing the bullet

```
Attack attack;
Vector3 targetCursorDestination;
Camera camera;

private float speed;
private float floatTime;
private float damage;
private Vector3 direction;

private void Awake() {
    GameObject MagePlayer = GameObject.Find("Player Red Mage(Clone)");
    attack = MagePlayer.GetComponent<Attack>();

    camera = attack.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Camera>();

    targetCursorDestination = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    transform.SetParent(null);
    gameObject.layer = 9;
}

void Start () {
    speed = attack.speed;
    floatTime = attack.floatTime;
    damage = attack.damage;

    direction = targetCursorDestination - transform.position;
    direction.Normalize();

    StartCoroutine(WaitingBullet(0));
}

IEnumerator WaitingBullet(float waitTime)
{
    //Set direction
    Vector3 targ = targetCursorDestination;
    targ.z = 0f;

    Vector3 objectPos = transform.position;
    targ.x = targ.x - objectPos.x;
    targ.y = targ.y - objectPos.y;

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(targ.y, targ.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(floatTime);
    // give the bullet some velocity to fly off in its set direction
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * (speed);

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: I note this question has attracted a vote to close for not including enough detail to diagnose the issue. Please consider editing your question to include enough sample code / description of your scene setup for another user to be able to reproduce your issue. Once we can reproduce the problem, we have a much better shot at being able to solve it. :)

Comment: @DMGregory Is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon awake you are using `GameObject.Find("")` to get the reference to a player character.

This provides the first `GameObject` of that name. Which in this case is the hosts character. By changing it to assigning the `Attack` class on instantiate it will solve this by specifying the correct instance. See below for the updated `Shoot()`

```
public void Shoot()
{
    // Create the bullet as a Gameobject we can reference from a prefab.
    GameObject Bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint) as GameObject;
    // Assign the correct instance of the Attack script.
    Bullet.GetComponent<BasicBullet>()._Attack = this.GetComponent<Attack>();
    // Set the bullets parent as null.
    Bullet.transform.SetParent(null);
}
```

When it comes to `BasicBullet`, it appears that your `Awake()` function can be removed split into the `Start()` and the `Shoot()` functions, see below to see how I have altered it to use the current player camera.

```
void Start()
{
    // Get the reference to the correct Camera using Attack Instance
    _Camera = _Attack.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Camera>();
    // Get required Destination from the Mouse Pointer
    targetCursorDestination = _Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    gameObject.layer = 9;

    direction = targetCursorDestination - transform.position;
    direction.Normalize();

    StartCoroutine(WaitingBullet(0));
}

IEnumerator WaitingBullet(float waitTime)
{
    //Set direction
    Vector3 targ = targetCursorDestination;
    targ.z = 0f;

    Vector3 objectPos = transform.position;
    targ.x = targ.x - objectPos.x;
    targ.y = targ.y - objectPos.y;

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(targ.y, targ.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_Attack.floatTime);
    // give the bullet some velocity to fly off in its set direction
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * (_Attack.speed);

    yield return null;
}
```

For this test I did set it up to use `Monobehaviour` not `NetworkBehaviour`. This had 2 cameras in the scene instead and the 2 players that called fire got the correct camera reference.

Comment: After some experimentation, It seems as though your idea of it finding the first player rather than the local player is correct, however, your solution caused the bullets to stop moving (they just sit in place when they're instantiated).

Comment: This is interesting: I added a `Debug.Log("Attack Before: " + attack);` before it uses `GameObject.Find("")` and one after and it gave me this: `Attack Before:` `Attack After: Player Red Mage(Clone) (Attack)`

Comment: When instantiating the bullet, are you calling that function from the player script or are you calling it from the attack script itself?

Comment: It's being called from the attack script, which is another script attached to the player

Comment: @IcecreamSwirlys did the edited answer above provide any assistance in the matter?

Comment: THANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOU IT WORKS!!!!